# How to fix innerHTML on IE not rendering entities with HTML5 doctype?

Tags: javascript, html

I'm observing that when using an HTML5 doctype (`<!DOCTYPE html>)`, assigning a string containing HTML entities to a DOM object's innerHTML does not convert/render those entities on IE8 (and probably other IE versions).

```
document.getElementById('some-div').innerHTML = 'Doesn&apos;t work.';
```

Does anybody have a solution? I've come across this: http://ajaxian.com/archives/innershiv-make-innerhtml-html5-work-in-ie, but it doesn't remedy the situation. The example I give above is of an element that's already on the DOM anyways.

Comment: Did you bother testing it with a HTML 4 DTD?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's `&apos;` (and it does not work even using HTML4.01 DOCTYPE).
Other HTML entities like `&copy; &amp;` etc work perfectly both IE7 and IE8.

`&apos;` does not work in IE (it's not because of HTML5 DOCTYPE, it's the same with other DOCTYPE). 
Also [here](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_entities.asp) they say it does not work, use `&#39;` as apostrophe

Comment: That's the ticket - thanks. Didn't even occur to me that it was &#apos; specifically.